# Почему таблица СДНФ не такая, как должна быть, и почему СКНФ получается с точностью наоборот и его таблица тоже не правильная?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
print("Записать логическую функцию по ее таблице истинности: ")
df = pd.DataFrame(
       [[0,0,0,1],
        [0,0,1,1],
        [0,1,0,0],
        [0,1,1,0],
        [1,0,0,1],
        [1,0,1,1],
        [1,1,0,0],
        [1,1,1,1]],
        columns = ["x1", "x2", "x3", "F(x1,x2,x3)"]
      )
print(df)
print("Решение: ")
print("Воспользуемся правилом построения СДНФ:")
r = (~df.loc[df['F(x1,x2,x3)']==1, ['x1','x2','x3']].astype(bool)).astype('int8') #.loc - Доступ к группе строк и столбцов по меткам (-ам) или логическому массиву.
print(r)
print("Получим СДНФ:")
res = (r.apply(lambda r: '({}{} ^ {}{} ^ {}{})'.format('!'*r['x1'], 'x1',
                                                        '!'*r['x2'], 'x2',
                                                        '!'*r['x3'], 'x3'),
                                                        axis=1)
    .str.cat(sep = ' v '))
print("СДНФ = ",res)
print("Воспользуемся правилом построения СКНФ:")
r_1 = (~df.loc[df['F(x1,x2,x3)']==0, ['x1','x2','x3']].astype(bool)).astype('int8') #.loc - Доступ к группе строк и столбцов по меткам (-ам) или логическому массиву.
print(r_1)
print("Получим СКНФ:")
res_1 = (r_1.apply(lambda r_1: '({}{} ^ {}{} ^ {}{})'.format('!'*r_1['x1'], 'x1',
                                                        '!'*r_1['x2'], 'x2',
                                                        '!'*r_1['x3'], 'x3'),
                                                        axis=1)
    .str.cat(sep = ' v '))
print("СКНФ = ",res_1)
```

Первая картинка это таблица СДНФ, которая должна была получится, вторая это таблица СКНФ, которая должна была получится, а третья это СКНФ, которое должно было получится.
[image: Вот таблица СДНФ, которая должна была получится:]
[image: Вот таблица СКНФ, которая должна была получится:]
[image: СКНФ, которое должно было получится]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По [правилам построения СКНФ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8A%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0) нам нужны строки для которых результат функции равен нулю:

```
In [25]: tmp = df.loc[df['F(x1,x2,x3)']==0, ['x1','x2','x3']]

In [26]: tmp
Out[26]:
   x1  x2  x3
2   0   1   0
3   0   1   1
6   1   1   0

In [27]: sknf = (tmp.apply(lambda r: '({}{} v {}{} v {}{})'.format('!'*r['x1'], 'x1',
    ...:                                                           '!'*r['x2'], 'x2',
    ...:                                                           '!'*r['x3'], 'x3'),
    ...:                   axis=1)
    ...:            .str.cat(sep = ' ^ '))

In [28]: sknf
Out[28]: '(x1 v !x2 v x3) ^ (x1 v !x2 v !x3) ^ (!x1 v !x2 v x3)'
```

Comment: У меня тоже такой ответ получился, но он должен быть с точностью наоборот другим. Там, где есть "!", не должно его быть, а где его нет, он должен быть.

Comment: Исправил, для построения СКНФ не нужно инвертировать вспомогательную таблицу

Comment: Спасибо большое.